# How to apply a custom JsonConverter to the values inside a list inside a dictionary?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonconverter

I have a `CustomConverter : JsonConverter<int>` for integers, and I need to add a `[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomConverter))]` attribute to a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` property. Applying the custom converter to an `int`, `List` or `Dictionary` works fine:

```
public class Example 
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomConverter))]
    public int ExampleInt { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(CustomConverter))]
    public List<int> ExampleList { get; set; }
    
    // How do I specify the Converter attribute for the int in the following line?
    public Dictionary<string, List<int>> ExampleDictionary { get; set; }
}
```

However I can't figure out how to specify that the CustomConverter should be used for the `int` values inside the `List` inside the `Dictionary`.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dictionary<string, List<int>>` is a nested collection of collections, and you are looking for something like `ItemOfItemsConverterType`, corresponding to [`ItemConverterType`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm), to specify a converter for the items of the items of the collection.  Unfortunately, no such attribute is implemented.  Instead, it will be necessary to create a converter for the nested `List<int>` collection that calls the required innermost item converter.

This can be done by implementing the following `JsonConverter` [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) for `List<>`:

```
public class ListItemConverterDecorator : JsonConverter
{
    readonly JsonConverter itemConverter;
    
    public ListItemConverterDecorator(Type type) => 
        itemConverter = (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(type ?? throw new ArgumentNullException());

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) =>
        !objectType.IsPrimitive && objectType != typeof(string) && objectType.BaseTypesAndSelf().Any(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>));
    
    public override bool CanRead => itemConverter.CanRead;
    public override bool CanWrite => itemConverter.CanWrite;
    
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var itemType = objectType.BaseTypesAndSelf().Where(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)).Select(t => t.GetGenericArguments()[0]).First();
        if (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartArray)
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unexpected token {0}, expected {1}", reader.TokenType, JsonToken.StartArray));
        var list = existingValue as IList ?? (IList)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator();
        while (reader.ReadToContentAndAssert().TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray)
            list.Add(itemConverter.ReadJson(reader, itemType, null, serializer));
        return list;
    }
    
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        foreach (var item in (IList)value)
            if (item == null)
                writer.WriteNull();
            else
                itemConverter.WriteJson(writer, item, serializer);
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader ReadToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader) =>
        reader.ReadAndAssert().MoveToContentAndAssert();

    public static JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)       // Skip past beginning of stream.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return reader;
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream.");
        return reader;
    }
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> BaseTypesAndSelf(this Type type)
    {
        while (type != null)
        {
            yield return type;
            type = type.BaseType;
        }
    }
}
```

Then annotate your `Example` class as follows, using [`JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemConverterParameters`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterParameters.htm) to specify the inner item converter `CustomConverter`:

```
public class Example 
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomConverter))]
    public int ExampleInt { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(CustomConverter))]
    public List<int> ExampleList { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(ListItemConverterDecorator), 
                  ItemConverterParameters = new object [] { typeof(CustomConverter) })]
    public Dictionary<string, List<int>> ExampleDictionary { get; set; }
}
```

And now you should be all set.  Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UGt60V).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, works great!

Answer (score -1):

For implementing this functionality you need to create CustomClass and inheriting it IDictionary

```
public class CustomClass : IDictionary<string, List<int>>
```

then you can use this class something like below:

```
public class Example {
   [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomConverter)]
   public string ExampleString { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(CustomConverter))]
   public List<int> ExampleList { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(CustomConverter))]
   public CustomClass data { get; set; }
}
```

Let me know you need any other information.

Comment: Assuming you meant `CustomClass : Dictionary<string, List<int>>` not `CustomClass : IDictionary<string, List<int>>`, this doesn't seem to work.  Json.NET still tries to apply the `CustomConverter` to the values of the dictionary, not the values of the values of the dictionary.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/0EqVPe which fails with a *`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Converter cannot write specified value to JSON. System.Int32 is required.`*.

Comment: Even with `CustomClass : IDictionary<string, List<int>>` the result should be the same.  Json.NET handles all dictionaries - whether inheriting from `Dictionary<,>` or just implementing `IDictionary<,>` - in the same way.