# How to apply ItemConverterType when deserializing a jagged array?

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I have existing attributes that properly use my 'InternedString' converter:

```
[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType=typeof(InternedString))]
public string[] prizeTypes;
```

Is there an easy way to apply it to a [jagged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) 2d array of strings, without writing my own `string[][]` converter?

```
[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType=typeof(InternedString))]
public string[][] prizeTypesByRoomType;
```

(It gives me a "Can not convert Array to String" exception which is obvious, but I was sort of hoping it could apply the type recursively)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json.NET does not have functionality to apply, using attributes, a custom `JsonConverter` to the items of the items of a jagged array such as `string [][]`. [`ItemConverterType`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm) only applies to the items of the outermost array.

What you can do is to apply the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) to create a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) that wraps some inner item converter for the innermost items of jagged arrays of arbitrary depth.

First, define the following converter:

```
public class JaggedArrayItemConverterDecorator : JsonConverter
{
    readonly JsonConverter itemConverter;

    public JaggedArrayItemConverterDecorator(Type type) => 
        itemConverter = (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(type ?? throw new ArgumentNullException());

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType.IsJaggedRankOneArray(out var itemType) && itemConverter.CanConvert(itemType);

    public override bool CanRead => itemConverter.CanRead;
    public override bool CanWrite => itemConverter.CanWrite;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartArray)
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unexpected token {0}, expected {1}", reader.TokenType, JsonToken.StartArray));
        var itemType = objectType.GetElementType();
        IList list = (IList)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(itemType)).DefaultCreator();
        while (reader.ReadToContentAndAssert().TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray)
        {
            if (itemType.IsArray)
                list.Add(ReadJson(reader, itemType, null, serializer));
            else
                list.Add(itemConverter.ReadJson(reader, itemType, null, serializer));
        }
        var array = Array.CreateInstance(itemType, list.Count);
        list.CopyTo(array, 0);
        return array;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var itemType = value.GetType().GetElementType();
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        foreach (var item in (IList)value)
        {
            if (item == null)
                writer.WriteNull();
            else if (itemType.IsArray)
                WriteJson(writer, item, serializer);
            else
                itemConverter.WriteJson(writer, item, serializer);
        }
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader ReadToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader) =>
        reader.ReadAndAssert().MoveToContentAndAssert();

    public static JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)       // Skip past beginning of stream.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return reader;
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream.");
        return reader;
    }
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static bool IsJaggedRankOneArray(this Type type, out Type innermostItemType)
    {
        innermostItemType = null;
        var currentType = type ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
        while (currentType.IsArray)
        {
            if (currentType.GetArrayRank() != 1)
                return false;
            currentType = currentType.GetElementType();
        }
        if (currentType != type)
        {
            innermostItemType = currentType;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you can apply it to jagged arrays of arbitrary depth in your model as follows:

```
public class Model
{
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType=typeof(InternedString))] // For 1d arrays you can use either ItemConverterType=typeof(InternedString) or JaggedArrayItemConverterDecorator
    public string[] prizeTypes { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(JaggedArrayItemConverterDecorator), typeof(InternedString))]
    public string[] prizeTypesByRoomType { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(JaggedArrayItemConverterDecorator), typeof(InternedString))]
    public string[][] prizeTypesByRoomType2d { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(JaggedArrayItemConverterDecorator), typeof(InternedString))]
    public string[][][] prizeTypesByRoomType3d { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(JaggedArrayItemConverterDecorator), typeof(InternedString))]
    public string[][][][] prizeTypesByRoomType4d { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType=typeof(InternedString))] // ItemConverterType works for multidimensional arrays
    public string[,] prizeTypesMultidimensional { get; set; }
}
```

Notes:

- The converter is implemented for arrays, not lists.  If you need to support jagged lists, see *[How to apply a custom JsonConverter to the values inside a list inside a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66238081/3744182)*.
- The converter is not implemented for multidimensional arrays such as `string [,]`, or for jagged arrays containing multidimensional arrays.  However, `ItemConverterType` does in fact support multidimensional arrays, so unless you have jagged arrays of multidimensional arrays or vice versa you should be all set.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HyB7qz).